# Load nested xml tag into BQ array type

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I call an API to get update details for some ids in one request. The API response format is XML. Depends on the id, the scheme of the xml can slightly be different. This data is stored in Bigquery and I have a few fields in final table as Record Repeated type for example:

```
 title 
      title.size
      title.type
      title.subtype
      title.lang
 cast 
      cast.name
      cast.lang
      cast.text
```

The XML looks like this for an API call:

```
<id id='id1'>
 <titles lang="en"> 
     <title size="120" type="full" subType="Main" lang="en">Mom</title> 
     <title size="70" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title> 
     <title size="40" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title>
     <title size="20" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title>
     <title size="10" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title> 
</titles>
<abc> </abc>
<description></description>
</id>
<id id='id2'>
<casts lang="en"> 
     <cast name="abcd" lang="en">abcs</cast> 
     <cast name="acbbb" lang="en">abcs33</cast> 
     <cast name="abcs" lang="en">abcs45</cast> 
     <cast name="abcsd" lang="en">abcs56</cast> 
     <cast name="abcwe" lang="en">abcs67</cast> 
</casts>
<abc> </abc>
<description></description>
</id>
```

I first tried to convert the xml file to json and loaded it to BQ, but as the scheme is not fix, couldn't leverage this method. As far as I searched, using pandas dataframe is not efficient too, correct me if I am wrong.

How can I load this data to BQ in python?

Comment: You should post several different schemes so that others can help you. And post the code you've tried.

Comment: @dabingsou I think only to know the scheme is not the same for every id, it is sufficient? I will add a sample any way...

Comment: OK, I'll give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll print out the data and assemble it yourself:)

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<id id='id1'>
 <titles lang="en"> 
     <title size="120" type="full" subType="Main" lang="en">Mom</title> 
     <title size="70" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title> 
     <title size="40" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title>
     <title size="20" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title>
     <title size="10" type="red" lang="en">Mom</title> 
</titles>
<abc> </abc>
<description></description>
</id>
<id id='id2'>
<casts lang="en"> 
     <cast name="abcd" lang="en">abcs</cast> 
     <cast name="acbbb" lang="en">abcs33</cast> 
     <cast name="abcs" lang="en">abcs45</cast> 
     <cast name="abcsd" lang="en">abcs56</cast> 
     <cast name="abcwe" lang="en">abcs67</cast> 
</casts>
<abc> </abc>
<description></description>
</id>
'''
dic = {}
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# ids = doc.selects('id') # Get all ids
# child = ids.child # Gets the first child node of each id
# children = child.children # Gets all child nodes
ids = doc.selects('id').child.children
for id in ids:
  for item in id:
    print ({i:item[i] for i in item if i != 'html'}, item.text)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'title', 'size': '120', 'type': 'full', 'subType': 'Main', 'lang': 'en'} Mom
{'tag': 'title', 'size': '70', 'type': 'red', 'lang': 'en'} Mom
{'tag': 'title', 'size': '40', 'type': 'red', 'lang': 'en'} Mom
{'tag': 'title', 'size': '20', 'type': 'red', 'lang': 'en'} Mom
{'tag': 'title', 'size': '10', 'type': 'red', 'lang': 'en'} Mom
{'tag': 'cast', 'name': 'abcd', 'lang': 'en'} abcs
{'tag': 'cast', 'name': 'acbbb', 'lang': 'en'} abcs33
{'tag': 'cast', 'name': 'abcs', 'lang': 'en'} abcs45
{'tag': 'cast', 'name': 'abcsd', 'lang': 'en'} abcs56
{'tag': 'cast', 'name': 'abcwe', 'lang': 'en'} abcs67
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: How to load this format to record repeated type in BQ?

Comment: I don't know what BQ data looks like. Can you give me an example

Comment: @daingsou I put example on top, the type of data is repeated record

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to deal with BQ data.